# Why nested transactions are not supported in JTA

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, transactions, jta, nested-transactions

Why aren't nested transactions supported by JTA? Is it because of the complexity of implementing them (which I doubt) or some design principle?

Comment: There is a good article about nested transactions, JTA and XA: http://jbossts.blogspot.com/2009/03/nested-transaction-support.html

Comment: I wonder if what I did will help you. Check it out  here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184703/hibernate-4-1-9-latest-final-build-reporting-nested-transactions-not-supporte/14191015#14191015

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(As @Piotr Nowicki points out, JTA *does* allow nested transactions, but this is optional not mandatory.)

Why?  This is one of those questions that is impossible to answer with any certainty, unless you were one of the people "in the room" when the decisions were made.

- It could be the inherent complexity of including nested transactions as part of the spec.  Or apparent complexity at the time; i.e. they weren't sure they knew how to do a *good job* of specifying them.
- It could be that they thought there wasn't enough demand.
- It could be time pressure ... or just plain exhaustion.
- It could be "commercial reasons"; e.g. certain vendors not wanting to interfere with product launch schedules by expanding the scope of the spec.

But, the bottom line is that if you want the *real* answer, you would need to ask the people in the working group that wrote JTA specifications.  (And I doubt they would tell you ... on the record.)

Answer (score 4):

JTA specification is not saying that the it doesn't support the nested transactions - it just **doesn't require** the implementors to support it.

Following excerpts are taken from the JTA 1.1 spec:

p. 11, 13; *3.1 UserTransaction interface* and *3.2 TransactionManager interface*

> "Support for nested tranactions is **not required**."

p. 13, *3.2.1 Starting a Transaction*

> "**If the Transaction Manager implementation does not support nested transactions**, the
>   TransactionManager.begin method throws the NotSupportedException when the
>   calling thread is already associated with a transaction."

There might be actually a problem with the `XAResource` that you might try enlisting with the current transaction (I believe it might be related with the X/Open XA specification):

*3.4.4 Transaction Association*

> **XAResource does not support** nested transactions. It is an error for the
>   XAResource.start method to be invoked on a connection that is currently associated
>   with a different transaction.

Comment: This may be in the spec but JTA's [@Transactional](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/Transactional.html) annotation [**doesn't**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/Transactional.TxType.html) include `NESTED` in the list of possible values. Although interestingly, Spring's [@Transactional](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) annotation [**does**](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html).

Answer (score 3):

Its neither the answer is business.

Many containers such as JBoss provide more complex alternative transaction managers which support concepts like nested transactions, but others like glassfish do not. Yet both of these are Java EE compliant. The idea is to keep the spec simple to lower the barrier of compliance for vendors.

Why force someone to implement a complex transaction manager that only covers .5% of transactional use cases or forgo Java EE compliance?

Nothing stops ambitious vendors from going above and beyond the specification, but they don't have the option to leave anything out.