# How to avoid nested transactions not supported error?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, transactions

I need to make sure many concurrent users be able to access the database. Although after each commit I close the session but sometimes my code runs into following error, but when I do the same operation for few times it surpass the error and works.

My hibernate is 4.2.1.Final

```
Messages:   
nested transactions not supported
File:   org/hibernate/engine/transaction/spi/AbstractTransactionImpl.java
Line number:    152
```

**My Code**

```
session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
session.getTransaction().begin();       OR session.beginTransaction();
       ...   to do ....
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();                        OR HibernateUtil.closeSession();
```

**HibernateUtil**

```
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class HibernateUtil {

   private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;
   private static final ThreadLocal<Session> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal();
   private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static SessionFactory configureSessionFactory() {
        try {

            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();
            serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder()
                                 .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                                 .buildServiceRegistry();
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

            return sessionFactory;
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            System.out.append("** Exception in SessionFactory **");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       return sessionFactory;
  }


  static {
    try {
      sessionFactory = configureSessionFactory();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println("%%%% Error Creating SessionFactory %%%%");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private HibernateUtil() {
  }

  public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
  }

  public static Session getSession() throws HibernateException {
    Session session = threadLocal.get();

    if (session == null || !session.isOpen()) {
      if (sessionFactory == null) {
        rebuildSessionFactory();
      }
      session = (sessionFactory != null) ? sessionFactory.openSession() : null;
      threadLocal.set(session);
    }

    return session;
  }

  public static void rebuildSessionFactory() {
    try {
      sessionFactory = configureSessionFactory();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println("%%%% Error Creating SessionFactory %%%%");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void closeSession() throws HibernateException {
    Session session = (Session) threadLocal.get();
    threadLocal.set(null);

    if (session != null) {
      session.close();
    }
  }
}
```

**Configuration**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">
            com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        </property>
        <property name="connection.url">
            jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyProject
        </property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">12</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">
            org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
        </property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

                <mapping class="com.project.common.Project" />
                <mapping class="com.project.common.School" />
                <mapping class="com.project.common.Address" />
                <mapping class="com.project.common.Female" />
                <mapping class="com.project.common.Male" />
                <mapping class="com.project.common.Credential" />
                <mapping class="com.project.common.Users" />

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Looks like a race hazard to me; there are many pitfalls to writing your own `ThreadLocal` scoped transactions. I would strongly advise against writing your own session management code, use one of the [`CurrentSessionContext`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/context/CurrentSessionContext.html) implementations provided.

Comment: do you know of any example?

Comment: Maybe start with [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/architecture.html#architecture-current-session).

Comment: have a look at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-demarcation-nonmanaged

Comment: @TimNorman I have already read that, but could not solve the issue.

Comment: Which version of Hibernate, database, and application server are you using? Is there a JTA transacation manager? Your "My code" snippet does not handle exceptions at all. Even if it is successful, `session.close()` does NOT reset the `ThreadLocal` variable, this is different from `HibernateUtils.closeSession()`. Have you checked that [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14184703/2390083)?

Comment: @Beryllium question is updated

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In your "My code" snippet, there might be some problems:

1. In case of an exception, there is no `finally` block to close the session
2. You are calling `session.close()`, but this is different from `HibernateUtils.closeSession()`. So the `ThreadLocal` is not cleared.
3. There is no `catch` block for exceptions; as a consequence there is no `rollback`.
4. Do you rethrow exceptions or are they (silently) ignored?

If there is an exception in the "to do" block after `begin()`, the transaction remains open, and `ThreadLocal` is not cleared.

Your code may work fine normally, but under high load there might be (SQL lock) timeouts etc., and in this case, once in a while, an exception will be thrown.

So check *each* snippet for *correct* exception handling:

```
final Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
try {
  final Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
  try {
    // The real work is here
    transaction.commit();
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    // Log the exception here
    transaction.rollback();
    throw ex;
  }
} finally {
  HibernatilUtil.closeSession();
}
```

---

You could add some "book-keeping" code to `HibernateUtil.getSession()` and `HibernateUtil.closeSession()`: Log each access, including the thread's name. Eventually one or multiple "gets" by the same thread must be followed by a "close".

In your case I would even consider to have only one "get", and pass the session around as long as your thread is doing its unit of work: This way it's possibly easier to find the problem.

---

There is another question on SO which reports a similar problem: [Hibernate 4.1.9 (latest final build) reporting `nested transactions not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14184703/2390083).

You could add some code after `commit()` to check, if the transaction has been really completed (by calling `wasCommitted()`).

A quote from the Javadoc of `wasCommitted()`:

> This method could return false even after successful invocation of commit(). As an example, JTA based strategies no-op on commit() calls if they did not start the transaction; in that case, they also report wasCommitted() as false.

Comment: thanks for your answer, do you think the current settings of mine are enough to handle large number of users?

Comment: @Mir Moorido Is your main problem resolved? You haven't selected an answer yet. Anyway it's hard to tell if your settings are suitable for a large number of users. You should set up a test with different numbers of concurrent users.

Comment: I have used it in my code but did not have much time to test it, will test it and let you know thanks

Comment: @MirMoorido Thanks for the 2nd bounty, very noble indeed. I am curious about which measure/action helped you out?

Comment: No worries, you deserved it, it does not show the same error anymore and I believe thats because of the correct exception handling and using HibernateUtil.closesession() thanks anyway.

Answer (score 17):

You probably have begun a transaction, and trying to begin another one without having committed or rollbacked the previous one. The idiom when using programmatic transaction demarcation is the following one:

```
Transaction transaction = null;
    try {
      session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
      transaction  = session.beginTransaction();
       ...   to do ....
      transaction.commit();
    }
    catch (RuntimeException e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        throw e;
    }
```

Add the following property in your Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
 <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
```

Comment: Thanks question is upated

Comment: I thought I need to, do you know of its pros and cons ?

Comment: With Hibernate 4+ this property brings another nightmare:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18832889/spring-transactions-and-hibernate-current-session-context-class

Answer (score 7):

Use session.beginTransaction() instead of session.getTransaction().begin() in your code. You need to begin a new unit of work, so beginTransaction will begin a new transaction.
So your code will look like:

```
session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
       ...   to do ....
transaction.commit();
```

Click [Here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/Session.html#beginTransaction%28%29) to get more information about beginTransaction(); method.

I think that will resolve your issue. Please let me know if issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem , i solved my problem by putting tr.commit(); function after every transaction.
It happens only when you start any transaction without closing previous transaction.

```
session = HibernateUtil.getSession();

session.getTransaction().begin();       OR session.beginTransaction();

...   to do ....

session.getTransaction().commit();

session.close();   OR HibernateUtil.closeSession();
```

Looks like you are also doing same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue :
org.hibernate.TransactionException: nested transactions not supported

In my case, I opened a session and tried saving . Without commit, I called another method and called session.beginTransaction();
So it throw the error.
In order to avoid, I sent the session object as a method parameter and just called session.save instead of again doing begin. Practically used the session object.
It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

So instead of Taking `transaction.begin()` we can use `session.getTransaction().begin()` and make sure `session` and `sessionfactory` are closed in finally block