# How to verify existence of a record in database?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

I need to verify the existence of a record in database, but regardless of the id that I pass to the following code, it does not show anything. either the record exists or not.

```
       session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Query q = session.createQuery("select count(*) from Users where id = :id");
        q.setInteger("id", id);
        Integer count = (Integer)q.uniqueResult();
        if(count > 0) {
            System.err.println(">");
        }
        else {
            System.err.println("<");
        }
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
```

I've used the following code as well but still have the same problem

```
  try{
        session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Users users = null;
        users = (Users) session.load(Users.class, id);
    }catch(Exception e){
              System.err.println("<");
      }
```

Comment: which one is execute for you if or else

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to use projection for getting result.

```
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Users.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("Id", Id));
    criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
    long count = (Long) criteria.uniqueResult();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
   if(count != 0){
       System.out.println("present");
   else{
       System.out.println("absent");
   }
```

Comment: Try to use this int count = ((Long) criteria.uniqueResult()).intValue();

Comment: What is the difference between our codes? I did not get the cause of issue, please have a look at this question as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17542157/how-to-avoid-nested-transactions-not-supported-error

Comment: UniqueResult may return the size which can not be suffix by Interger.And Second code Session.Load wont throw exception until you access any method on Loaded object.

Comment: I see all right, thanks please have a look at the other question as well. I am really interested in finding an answer for that.

Comment: If i want to check multiple records then @MayurB

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `Session.load` method, if none exists a HibernateException will be thrown

```
Session session = // get session..
Users u = null;
try {
  u = (Users) session.load(Users.class, userId);
} catch (HibernateException e) {
  // No Users with id 'userId' exists
}
```

Comment: I've changed it and used }catch(Exception e) but has not solved it

Comment: Session.load will give you a proxy object of Users class.It wont throw ObjectNotFountException until you do any operation on Users u object....

Comment: Also, as per docs, `session.get()` is preferred to check existence rather than `load()`

Answer (score 0):

use session.get method,and use only exception for this case

```
 try
   {s = (student) session1.get(student.class, 16);
   System.out.println("the result is"+s.marks);
   } 


 catch(Exception e)
   {

    System.out.println("none");
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have EntityManager instance
Then you could do.

```
entityManager.find(Users.class, 1002L);
```

the second parameter is the primarykey Id of the record.

will return null if no records exist.
will throw IllegalArgumentException if primaryKey is not inferred/unrecognizable.