# entitymanager, transaction in transaction

Tags: jpa, transactions, entitymanager

I have such code :

```
   public void createTerminal(TerminalDo terminalDo) {
        final EntityManagerFactory emf = JpaFactory.getEntityManagerFactory();
        final EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction etx = null;
        try {
            etx = em.getTransaction();
            etx.begin();

            // persist method make the passed Object stored in the persistence
            // context
            em.persist(terminalDo);

            etx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (etx != null && etx.isActive())
                etx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
   }
```

This is a transactional method.
I don't know if it's possible to create another transactional method calling this already transactional one,
then nesting an entity-managed transaction into another one,
and is it a good practice ?

```
       public void makeAllThat(TerminalDo terminalDo, ApplicationDo applicationDo) {
            final EntityManagerFactory emf = JpaFactory.getEntityManagerFactory();
            final EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
            EntityTransaction etx = null;
            try {
                etx = em.getTransaction();
                etx.begin();

                createTerminal(terminalDo);
                createApplication(applicationDo);
                //do many other transactions...
                .....

                etx.commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (etx != null && etx.isActive())
                    etx.rollback();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                em.close();
            }
       }
```

Comment: I think you want to achieve what is called _transaction propagation_ in JPA.

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Is it possible to do "transaction propagation" with JPA, or is it only possible with Spring ? Or maybe CDI ?

Comment: Sorry for a late answer. From JPA point of view the _transaction propagation_ term refers to sharing a single persistence context between multiple container-managed entity managers (transaction-scoped or extended) within a single JTA transaction. Take a closer look at `@TransactionAttribute` (EJB) or `@Transactional` (Spring) and choose a proper one for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask is called Nested Transactions. JPA alone does not specify anything about that. A Persistence Unit can be of two types: RESOURCE_LOCAL (your case, as you work with `EntityTransaction`) and JTA. Also JTA is known as [not requiring nested transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552198/why-nested-transactions-are-not-supported-in-jta). But your case is RESOURCE_LOCAL, which AFIK depends on your JDBC driver, database and database engine.

IMPORTANT NOTE: the example that you showed is an example of parallel transactions, as every `EntityManager` instance you create with `EntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()' is independent of each other. In your case, if`createApplication()`fails,`createTerminal()` will have its transaction commited (please do test it and comfirm that in a comment)!

Usually you come along without nested transaction and I would suggest using JTA transaction (with a framework that supports declarative transactions, like Spring or EJB), as it is really a standard nowadays.