# Transaction not committed at end of method

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, jboss, wildfly

I have two methods annotated with transactional (they are on the same level - have the same parent transaction, as sketched below):

```
@javax.transaction.Transactional
persist() {
    persistEntities1()
    persistEntities2()
}

@javax.transaction.Transactional(value = Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
persistEntities1() {}

@javax.transaction.Transactional(value = Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
persistEntities2() {}
```

In *persistEntities1* everything is OK, there is a merge call on EntityManager instance.
In *persistEntities2* there is an uncaught exception.

Problem: entities that should get persisted in *persistEntities1* do not get persisted.

Why is this happening? I thought that REQUIRES_NEW ensures that transaction gets committed at the end of method.

I am using Wildfly 8.2.

Comment: Are you commiting the transaction after the end of the first method?

Comment: No, not explicitly. I thought jboss manages transactions for me.

Comment: according to this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/Transactional.TxType.html, REQUIRES_NEW will create new transactions and will interrupt already going ones. So there's a possibility that your 2nd method is suspending the 1st transaction before it can commit. Have you tried REQUIRED?

Comment: No, this kind of behaviour is not allowed. It says in docs:
"If called inside a transaction context, the current transaction context must be suspended, a new JTA transaction will begin, the managed bean method execution must then continue inside this transaction context, the transaction must be completed, and the previously suspended transaction must be resumed."

Comment: Exactly. That means that when you call the 2nd method, anything that is happening at the 1st transaction will be suspended and resumed after the 2nd transaction ends.

Comment: Ok - but why didn't a transaction within persistEntities1() {} complete at the end of persistEntities1 method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69241/discussion-between-genesiss-and-dalton).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to move both methods `persistEntities1` and `persistEntities2`to separate bean. Now the behavior is as expected.

It seems that this specific jpa implementation ignores child transaction annotations if child methods live in same bean as parent method.

Comment: Could it be that this annotation only works on public methods? (like Spring) From your example it looks like you have friendly access on the method annotated with REQUIRES_NEW.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that would happen is because a `RuntimeException` was thrown within the execution of `persistEntities1()`.

See [why does transaction roll back on RuntimeException but not SQLException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125837/why-does-transaction-roll-back-on-runtimeexception-but-not-sqlexception).

It doesn't seem to matter whether the exception has been caught and handled or not, the transaction context still gets set to "rollback only".

Comment: They are both at the same level (they are called one after another) - they have the same parent transaction.

Comment: Are they being called from a transaction-managed scope? In other words, is there another transaction enveloping both calls?

Comment: But I have REQUIRED_NEW. The docs say that if REQUIRED_NEW is used, current transaction context gets suspended, a new JTA transaction begins and execution continues inside this context, then the transaction is completed and previously suspended transaction is resumed: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/Transactional.TxType.html#REQUIRES_NEW

Comment: What you say is true. Here are some other answers which seem to support your understanding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10817838/ejb-3-0-nested-transaction-requires-new and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552198/why-nested-transactions-are-not-supported-in-jta.

Comment: I've updated my answer based on the new information you've provided. See if that helps.

Comment: Actually - I am more confused now :) 1. persistEntities1() has no errors 2. persistEntities2() has an error --> I wrapped content of persistEntities2 in try-catch and now it works. It seems that parent transaction gets rolled back if there is an error in one of the children - even if children methods are annotated with REQUIRES_NEW attribute.  And also - it seems that if exception gets caught, transaction doesn't get set to "rollback only".

Comment: I understand an exception was *apparently* not thrown from `persistEntities1()`, but I'm pretty sure you will find there was in fact an exception thrown within its context, which was caught and handled.

Comment: If there is no exception in persistEntities2(), data from persistEntities1() gets persisted, so I think (in my framework/app server stack) that there is no exception in persistEntities1.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarifying, It seems Wildfly does not standardly implement JavaEE transaction behavior. Your parent transaction is rolling back when any of the child transactions fails. Have you looked for a related configuration setting in Wildfly?